# Select the first day and last day of this year in DB2

Tags: sql, date, select, db2

How to get the first day and the last day for the current year in DB2 in format YYYYMMDD?

I tried:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE),8,0)||'0101'
```

And:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE),8,0)||'1231
```

But it does not work till I put the year, but I need the year to be a parameter "not need to change it every year in the Query"

Comment: note that if you're planning on using this as part of a `WHERE` clause, it's stylistically more correct to do `< first_day_of_the_next_year` (even if in this case the types would truncate properly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
select
    date('0001-01-01') + year(current date) years - 1 year first_day_of_the_year,
    date('0001-01-01') + year(current date) years - 1 day  last_day_of_the_year
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=c7b174ea7a884be5266a4e9702cea391)**:

```
FIRST_DAY_OF_THE_YEAR | LAST_DAY_OF_THE_YEAR
--------------------: | -------------------:
           2020-01-01 |           2020-12-31
```

If you want the results as strings in `YYYYMMDD` format, you can format the results with `to_char()`:

```
select
    to_char(date('0001-01-01') + year(current date) years - 1 year, 'yyyymmdd') first_day_of_the_year,
    to_char(date('0001-01-01') + year(current date) years - 1 day, 'yyyymmdd')  last_day_of_the_year
from sysibm. sysdummy1
```

Comment: Since first and last date is always the same beside year, you can simplify to: `values date(year(current_date) || '-12-31')` etc

Comment: another way is: `SELECT this_year(current date), this_year(current date) + 1 year - 1 day FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;